# Minimum number of nodes in a Helix cluster

Tags: apache, scalability, apache-zookeeper, failover, helix

Since Zookeeper needs atleast 3 nodes to form a proper quorum, for the nodes to remain operating, I am assuming this translates to Helix as well.

I am looking to take an existing application and add scalability and failover capabilities to it. Now there are certain circumstance under which this application does not need to take heavy load, thus can compromise on scaling and failover. Thus I can use just one single machine.

Now I can do single machine for zookeeper but 2 is not recommended, right ?

So what is the minimum number of machines that I need to have so that I have the ability to add failover property to the application if I use Helix.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have failover property, you need at least two replicas for each partition and the replicas should be on different hosts.

So if you have a dedicated Zookeeper cluster already, at least two hosts you need to have failover property.

If you are going to use those machines for both Zookeeper cluster and Helix cluster, you need three since Zookeeper cluster need three nodes at least.